# Problems with the axis of spider/radar chart D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, radar-chart, spider-chart

I take an example of radar/spider chart done in D3.js. Here is the code in [codepen](https://codepen.io/hunterperez/pen/gzyBaQ). If I change the order of the objects of one of the two datasets I have, the chart changes. In this example I have the axes of the two dataset in the same order and it draws the chart correctly.

```
       //Data 
    var d = [
  [{
    axis: "Email",
    value: 0.59
  }, {
    axis: "Social Networks",
    value: 0.56
  }, {
    axis: "Internet Banking",
    value: 0.42
  }, {
    axis: "News Sportsites",
    value: 0.34
  }, {
    axis: "Search Engine",
    value: 0.48
  }, {
    axis: "View Shopping sites",
    value: 0.14
  }, {
    axis: "Paying Online",
    value: 0.11
  }, {
    axis: "Buy Online",
    value: 0.05
  }, {
    axis: "Stream Music",
    value: 0.07
  }, {
    axis: "Online Gaming",
    value: 0.12
  }, {
    axis: "Navigation",
    value: 0.27
  }, {
    axis: "App connected to TV program",
    value: 0.03
  }, {
    axis: "Offline Gaming",
    value: 0.12
  }, {
    axis: "Photo Video",
    value: 0.4
  }, {
    axis: "Reading",
    value: 0.03
  }, {
    axis: "Listen Music",
    value: 0.22
  }, {
    axis: "Watch TV",
    value: 0.03
  }, {
    axis: "TV Movies Streaming",
    value: 0.03
  }, {
    axis: "Listen Radio",
    value: 0.07
  }],

  [{
    axis: "Email",
    value: 0.48
  }, {
    axis: "Social Networks",
    value: 0.41
  }, {
    axis: "Internet Banking",
    value: 0.27
  }, {
    axis: "News Sportsites",
    value: 0.28
  }, {
    axis: "Search Engine",
    value: 0.46
  }, {
    axis: "View Shopping sites",
    value: 0.29
  }, {
    axis: "Paying Online",
    value: 0.11
  }, {
    axis: "Buy Online",
    value: 0.14
  }, {
    axis: "Stream Music",
    value: 0.05
  }, {
    axis: "Online Gaming",
    value: 0.19
  }, {
    axis: "Navigation",
    value: 0.14
  }, {
    axis: "App connected to TV program",
    value: 0.06
  }, {
    axis: "Offline Gaming",
    value: 0.24
  }, {
    axis: "Photo Video",
    value: 0.17
  }, {
    axis: "Reading",
    value: 0.15
  }, {
    axis: "Listen Music",
    value: 0.12
  }, {
    axis: "Watch TV",
    value: 0.1
  }, {
    axis: "TV Movies Streaming",
    value: 0.14
  }, {
    axis: "Listen Radio",
    value: 0.06
  }]
];
```

However, if I change the order of one of them, for example, the first two elements of the first dataset, the chart changes when it shouldn't.

```
//Data 
var d =
[
      [   {
            axis: "Social Networks",
            value: 0.56
          },
          {
            axis: "Email",
            value: 0.59
          }, ...
      ],
      [  {
           axis: "Email",
           value: 0.48
         }, 
         {
           axis: "Social Networks",
           value: 0.41
         }...
     ]
]
```

In the second case in the chart, "Email" takes 0.41 as value instead of 0.48 and the same happens with "Social Networks".

How can I draw the chart correctly in spite of the order? Is not the name of the axes enough?

Comment: The explanation here is quite simple: the code is mapping the first inner array of the data array to get the axes names: `var allAxis =(d[0].map(function(i, j) { return i.axis }));`. That's not a clever or flexible approach, as you just discovered. Who wrote that code, you?

Comment: I take the code from http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/6506614. I also tried with other examples I found and in all of them happen the same problem.

Comment: You already get the explanation.

Comment: Sorting them alphabetically based on the `axis` names should solve the problem.

Comment: Sorting them using **any** criterion, as long it is the same, solves the problem. Again, the issue here is that the code was written supposing that the order of the elements in the inner arrays is the same. By the way, it's worth mentioned that Nadieh Bremer, one of the best D3 programmers around, made that code to herself: that's why the code is not clever or flexible, she knows the order of the elements in the inner arrays.